# Passing object from getJSON to outside function?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pass the object "value" to the "hello()" function, but I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list note: [ opened at line 1,
>   column 6

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/users/all", function(result){
        $.each(result, function(key,value) {
            $("#data").append(
              '<li class="list-group-item\">' + 
                value.name + 
                '<a class="btn btn-light float-right" onclick="hello(' + value + ')" role="button">View Euclidean</a>' + 
                '<a class="btn btn-dark float-right mr-1 text-light" role="button">View Recommendations</a>' + 
              '</li>');
        });
    });
});

function hello(value) {
    console.log("hello" + value.name);
}
```

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is an example value?

Comment: You are getting a syntax error! [Your json object is missing a comma or closing bracket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_bracket_after_list)

Comment: If value is an object, if you are going to stick with inline bindings like that (you should really reconsider), I would suggest you `JSON.stringify(value)` for the onclick.  You're creating a text string.  There are no objects in a text string.

Comment: @Taplar The object just contains and id and a name. Let's say ID: 1, Name: 'Fred'.

Comment: @Taplar I get "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error if I do JSON.stringify(value)

Comment: Then you have some weirdness going on.  Can you please show us what the `result` looks like in the question?

Comment: @Taplar 0: Object { id: 1, name: "Fred" }

Comment: If that is what `result` is then your logic doesn't make sense, as the `key` would be `id` and `name`, so trying to do `value.name` in the loop doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Taplar basically I want to have access to the name of the person in each onclick. So when I press the button linked to lisa, I get hello lisa, and the one for fred will say hello fred.

Comment: You cannot concatenate an object like this: `'hello(' + value + ')'`

Comment: @connexo Any idea how I would go about passing the name to the hello function?

Comment: `'hello(' + value.name + ')'` and then `function hello(name) { console.log("hello" + name); }`.

Comment: @connexo That gives me an error saying that the name isn't defined.

Comment: Which part of the code is that error reported on? Have you adjusted the `hello() function` as I wrote, too?

Comment: @Lithicas: You'd have to surround the argument in quotes. The contents of `onclick` needs to be valid JS, embedded in the HTML attribute.

Comment: `'hello(\'' + value.name + '\')'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to append an object to a string:

```
'<a class="btn btn-light float-right" onclick="hello(' + value + ')" role="button">View Euclidean</a>'
```

...which causes `toString` to be called on the object, which usually converts to:

```
[Object object]
```

...hence the syntax error, because your `onclick` will now be:

```
hello([Object object])
```

...which is a syntax error.

You probably meant to do `+ JSON.stringify(value) +`.

An even better approach would be to not create the click handler through string manipulation:

```
const euclideanLink = $('<a class="btn btn-light float-right" role="button">View Euclidean</a>');
euclideanLink.click(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  hello(value.name);
  return false;
});
const recommendsLink = $('<a class="btn btn-dark float-right mr-1 text-light" role="button">View Recommendations</a>');

const listItem = $('<li class="list-group-item"/>');
listItem.append(value.name, euclideanLink, recommendsLink);

$("#data").append(listItem);
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I get ReferenceError: Lisa is not defined where Lisa is the name

Comment: Yeah, you'll want to pass the serialized object, then. Or see my edit for a way to do the click handler without stuffing it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you separate your markup from your javascript, and dynamically bind your event handler to the link, so you don't have to worry about converting it to a string or anything.

```js
//$(document).ready(function() {
//  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/users/all", function(result) {

    //fake out some results so we can see the logic in action
    var result = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Jane' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Jim' }
    ];
    
    //get the html from the template on the page so we don't have to put
    //it in the script
    var userTemplate = $('#userTemplate').html();
    
    $('#data').append(
      //create an array of all the elements to add to the data
      //doing this lets us append once, reducing the number of times we
      //touch the DOM
      $.map(result, function(value){
        //replace the {{name}} in the template with our real name
        var $newUser = $(userTemplate.replace(/\{\{name\}\}/, value.name));
        
        //find the first link and bind the click handler to it
        $newUser.find('.view-euclidean').on('click', function(){
          hello(value);
        });
        
        return $newUser;
      })
    );
//  });
//});

function hello(value) {
  console.log("hello" + value.name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="data"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="userTemplate">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    {{name}}
    
    <a class="btn btn-light float-right view-euclidean" role="button">
      View Euclidean
    </a>
    
    <a class="btn btn-dark float-right mr-1 text-light" role="button">
      View Recommendations
    </a>
  </li>
</script>
```